# Disable a EditText 1 when data is entered into EditText 2

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm fairly new to android programming, and I have the following situation:
 I'd like to have two editText fields, where if the user types data into the first, it disables the other field, meaning it's still visable but not editable by the user.

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this, but I haven't been able to find it.

Thank you for the help, and let me know if I'm missing any specific details,
Classy

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) It's important that you try things before you ask for help, or you will likely never learn to be a self-sufficient coder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `EditText.addTextChangedListener` to detect user input data.
Use `EditText.setEnabled(false)` to disable your second EditText.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                disableEditTExt.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
```

Hope this will help you going.

Comment: This works great, but it doesn't make it clear to the user that the textfield is unuseable, is there a built in way to have it grey out the field, or do I have to have an overlay appear?

Comment: Usually setting setEnabled(false) should grey out your views. Which device are you testing on? You can add setFocusable(false), and setClickable(false) to loose the focus.

Answer (score 0):

```
firstEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                secondEditTExt.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
```